# How can I get ACF data on WooCommerce template-homepage.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I cannot get my repeater to work on template-homepage.php.

I have created a group called 'homepage_settings' and in this group is a repeater called 'categories'. I cannot get this content to show on the template-homepage.php file.

```
    <ul class="medium-block-grid-3 small-block-grid-1" data-equalizer>
        <?php 
            $rows = get_field('categories');

            if($rows) {
                foreach($rows as $row) {
        ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>">
                            <span class="bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $row['image']; ?>')"></span>
                            <span class="title"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
        <?php
                }
            }       
        ?>  
    </ul>

No content is being displayed and no errors?
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to grab "homepage_settings" and not "categories" first.  Does this line of code print anything?

```
<?php 
    $rows = get_field('categories');

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($rows,1).'</pre>';
?>
```

If that doesn't produce anything, then you are grabbing the wrong field.  First grab homepage_settings and see if that has anything inside.

```
<?php 
    $rows = get_field('homepage_settings');

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($rows,1).'</pre>';
?>
```

That should have your "categories" data inside (make sure you have put content into the fields in the CMS).  Then, you can use a foreach to loop through it.

```
<?php
    foreach($rows['categories'] as $row) {
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($row,1).'</pre>';
    }
?>
```

That should be it.  Take it one variable at a time, and go from there.